# populating pinpoints on the locations retrived from sqlite datadase

Tags: android, sqlite, android-maps

I m new to android and trying to develop an app in which i want to retrive locations from sqlite db and show pinpoints on map for those locations. I have read many links and other questions here but m not geting any idea how to start working with it. Pls help me with some sample code or helpful links. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Android SQLite here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

To implement the maps read here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

If you show me what you tried I could help you.